# browser, navigation issues

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

This is basically a continuation of a question of mine from yesterday,
"Foregoing intialization on a page"

(And btw, kudos to all who give selflessly in this forum to help others - need to do more of that myself.)

So anyway, I was told about HistoryManager, BrowserManager and SharedObject, and so quickly ascertained that its no problem to store a few data items in a shared object so a flex page restores the previous configuration when the browser navigates back to it.

But my real concern would be speed of loading.  Its a 15mb page and it only takes 2 seconds to load, but that's still not instantaneous.  If it were in a tabbed browser and I just clicked on another tab containing my page, my page would then appear instantaneously.  Is there any way to achieve that behavior when my page is navigated back to (via the browser back button for example.)  Would that mean that the entire 15mb flex web page would have to be stored in memory.

Thanks.

Comment: 15 meg is *huge* for a web page.

Comment: That's not the download size - its the size in memory.  The donwload size is about a 1Mb

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm thinking, you're going the wrong way about this,(unless I missed the boad on what you want to acheive) what you need to do is work with javascript to interact with the browsers url. Thjis is assuming that you want to be able to go back on a page without reloading content.

Basicaly a java script would override the reloading, and when you hit back, the page doesn't reload, but the javascript notifies the flash what change in has occurred.

Have a look at the gaya framework for how they do it
or lookat http://www.robertpenner.com/experiments/backbutton/backbutton.html

Comment: I don't  yet see how it applies.  When you hit the browser 'back' button on his example, it apparently stays on that page and executes a function on his page.

What I want to do is as follows.  I have a url on my flash web page (in htmlText for example).  The user clicks on it, it takes them to some entirely different page, probably not even a flash page just somewhere else on the internet.  So then he clicks the browser 'back' button.  My page reloads again, but it takes like 2 seconds. Is there any way to make it instantaneous (like when you hit another tab in a tabbed browser

Comment: It could be there's some Javascript function I simply don't know about that says get this page from the 'cache' or wherever instead of reloading.

Comment: Its not a question of hitting the web server again, though.  Its not doing that currently

Comment: I guess you want to reload the page in an instance. I think you might be able to trick a browser into it in some way, but having it work on all browsers might be pretty difficult, as this would have something to do with the way the page is rendered rather than loaded, so this process is entirely internal.

    what you could do though is using a javascript to keep everything hidden, and reveal it once flash has loaded.